Uniform concentration bound (function-valued random variable / continuous stochastic process)
I'm trying to consider a probability space $\Omega$ and
$f(x,\xi):\mathcal{X}\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ (stochastic process over space? or function-valued random variable?), where $\mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is a compact subset. I also need the boundedness condition i.e. $|f(x,\xi)|\leq F$.
What I want to get is kind of uniform (over $\mathcal{X}$) concentration inequality given $n$ number of samples. My questions are as follows.

Is there a good theory of (bounded) function-valued random variable? (if so, please let me know some references)

If the answer to 1. is yes, Is there a (uniform) concentration inequality for such (bounded) function-valued random variable?


If a construction of this direction is not possible, I have also thought of another direction.
Let's consider a stochastic process indexed by $\mathcal{X}$. If we can assume that this process is always $L$-Lipschitz, then we can pick a finite number of points with suitable distances in $\mathcal{X}$ and apply Hoeffding's inequality for these points. Then by union bound and Lipschitzness, we can get a uniform concentration bound. My question is

Is it possible that there exists a stochastic process indexed by $\mathcal{X}$ which is always (or almost surely) L-Lipschitz?

My final question is

Is there a difference or inclusion relationship between the two setting (function-valued random variable / stochastic process indexed by domain)?

I would appreciate any kind answer or reference as I'm not familiar with any of these topic (I'm only familiar with real valued random variables and discrete time stochastic processes).
Thank you.

I am not sure whether I fully understand the question, but the standard epsilon net method might help, for proving a random process concentrates uniformly for all points. there are other options such as dudley ineuality, generic chaining, if there are dependency in the space.

@tony I defined a function-valued random variable as a measurable function from some probability space to the space of B-bounded, L-lipschitz functions on a compact subset $\mathcal{X}$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$, where the latter space is equipped with the uniform metric topology and the Borel sigma algebra induced by this topology. If I use this definition, everything I wanted seems fine.
By the way, can you let me know what the standard epsilon net method is? Is there any reference for it?

I'm not sure whether this would help: theorem 4.4.5  in https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf provides an example, see also https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/254a-notes-3-the-operator-norm-of-a-random-matrix/#more-3326

@tony I checked the links and I realized the setting is different with my situation. But thank you for your comment!

Let
$$\mathbb{F}=\{f:\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R} : |f(x)|\leq B, f\text{ is }L-\text{Lipschitz}\}.$$
We can give uniform metric
$$d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in\mathcal{X}}|f(x)-g(x)|$$
and it gives a metric topology to $\mathbb{F}$. We consider the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{F}$ induced by this topology. Let's say a \textit{random function} with value in $\mathbb{F}$ is a measurable function
$$X:\Omega\to \mathbb{F},$$ where $\left(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P\right)$ is a probability space.
For a fixed $x\in\mathcal{X}$, we define the evaluation map $\theta_x:\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{R}$ by sending $f$ to $f(x)$.
Then the following proposition, statements of which were what I needed, holds.
Proposition
A random function $X$ satisfies the followings.

$\theta_x\circ X$ is a real-valued random variable.
The event $\{ X(x)\leq c \text{ for all }x\in\mathcal{X}\}$ for any constant $c$ is measurable in $\mathbb{F}$.

proof
For the first statement, we only need to show that $\theta_x$ is a measurable function where $\mathbb{R}$ is equipped with the Lebesgue measure. By the definition of uniform norm,
$$|f(x)-g(x)|\leq \sup_{x\in\mathcal{X}}|f(x)-g(x)|\leq d(f,g),$$
i.e. $\theta_x$ is Lipschitz. It is known that Lipschitz function to $\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable.
For the second statement, let's denote a closed ball in $\mathbb{F}$ of radius $r$ centered at $f\in\mathbb{F}$ as $B_r(f)$. There exists $r>0$ such that $c-2r\leq -B$. Then the event $\{ X(x)\leq c \text{ for all }x\in\mathcal{X}\}$ is equal to $B_r(c-r)$. Thus, it is closed and hence Borel measurable.
